# No syntax highlighting after Vim session restore in Terminal

Tags: terminal, vim

I'm using this [Vim configuration](https://github.com/davidxia/vim-config). I save and restore Vim sessions using these 2 commands:

```
 :mksession! ~/.vim_session
 :source ~/.vim_session
```

There's no syntax highlighting after I restore a session. How can I fix this?

My Vim version:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3.462 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Mar 26 2012 21:45:48)
MacOS X (unix) version
Included patches: 1-462
```

Comment: Why not add `syntax on` in `.vimrc` to switch highlighting ON by default?

Answer (score 2):

There is a note at the end of the "Views and Sessions" chapter of [the documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#%3amkview) (see the last paragraph of this section). In particular, `:syntax on` is not restored by the session file.

Does it work if you enter `:syntax on` manually after loading the session?

Comment: Great find! I have been playing with session lately and was stuck by the lack of syntax after a restore as well. But I was rather suspecting a problem with my .vimrc than a "feature".

Comment: It doesn't work if I manually enter `:syntax on`. Does this mean there's no way to automatically highlight?

Comment: Perhaps try `:setf vim` (for example)